# alfresco community edition-5.1.x workflow drop-down field multi select value

Tags: java, alfresco, alfresco-webscripts

I am new to alfresco community edition-5.1.x ,I have created workflow activiti using kick-start after deployed alfresco work-flow activti is working successfully. In work-flow form drop-down fields i used is this possible to select multiple value please help me out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to define drop down fields in your share custom config form declarations:

```
               <config evaluator="task-type" condition="mytaskmodel:mytask">
                    <forms>
                        <form>
                            <field-visibility>                                  
                                <show id="mytaskmodel:myproperty" />
                            </field-visibility>
                            <appearance>
                                <field id="mytaskmodel:myproperty" />
                                <control template="/org/alfresco/components/form/controls/selectone.ftl">
                                    <control-param name="options">1|valueone,2|value2</control-param>
                                </control>
                                </field>
                            </appearance>
                        </form>
                    </forms>   
                </config>
```